# Linux: "Caching" Data for multiple processes

Tags: php, sql, linux, debian

Sorry for that title, I can´t find short words to describe my request.

On my Debian 9 Server I have a process that "creates" data. To simplyify it let´s just say the process (It´s php my the way) generates a integer. This value changes very frequently (less than every second). Now I want to make this number accessible to other processes. Considering the frequency of changes i assume storing the data in a sql database or a plain txt file on the file system is not the way to go. How should I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a shared memory segment.

Comment: But you'll need to implement mutual exclusion to prevent race conditions. Not sure how easy that is to do in PHP.

Comment: Instead of a plain text file you could use a binary file. But you'll still have the race condition problem.

Comment: You can use memcached.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I´ll check those ideas.

Comment: Also: I guess using anything else but the main memory is a wrong approach. After all the value changes so rapid and doesn´t need to be saved after a system reboot.

Comment: @Barmar I´ve decided to go with shared memory for now. Working fine so far for differnt php processes. Sadly one of my processes, that needs to access the data, is a Node.js process. I still have to see if i can get them to access the same memory block. If i don´t manage to do that, i might take this (horrible) workaround: Ill exec a shell command with node.js which calls a php script which then again returns the data stored in the shared memory block. I know it sounds awful and not very clean, but i guess it´s still faster than using any storageform that uses the harddisk. What do you think?